# How can I update a progress bar?

Tags: winapi, progress-bar

How can I update this progress bar in win32api? You can find the full code here [Code is here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19835281/main.cpp)

```
hProgress=CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, NULL,
                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                  20, 20, 260, 17,
                  hwnd, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message you are looking for is [PBM_SETPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The usage of this depends on what the range is currently set to (defaults from 0-100). For example, assuming the default range, setting the position to halfway would be done as so:

```
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETPOS, 50, 0);
```

Alternatively, the progress bar can be incremented in steps through [PBM_STEPIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The usage of this depends on what the step increment is (default to 10). For example, assuming the default range and initial position of the progress bar, stepping the position to 10 would be done as so:

```
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I try that and it does not work here is the full code.
[Code is here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19835281/main.cpp)

Comment: Your problem here is that `hProgress` falls out of scope. One quick fix is to make it static (`static HWND hProgress`).

Comment: ok i am at school will test when back home and ya i am at school age = 15

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `PMB_STEPIT` message to move the current position based on the step size:

```
int max_range = 1000;

// set range of progress bar
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, max_range));

// set the step size
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM) 1, 0); 

// increment by step size
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
```

Here is a good example [`How to Use Progress Bar Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have initialised common controls :

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrlEx;

InitCtrlEx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
InitCtrlEx.dwICC  = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrlEx);
```

Set the range:

```
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(min, max));
```

Set the position:

```
SendMessage(hProgress,PBM_SETPOS,pos,0);
```

See: [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: it get this
error: `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: @iphone4life4 I know it's an old comment, but someone else might find it useful. It's most likely because you forgot to link `Comctl32.lib`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to updating the progress in the progress bar, you must also give it a chance to repaint. Usually you're showing a progress bar because you're busy working, and so the normal message loop isn't running and no WM_PAINT messages are generated. You can call [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) to repaint the window immediately.